# Faster way to 'git show' without running a process each time

Tags: git, perl, show

I have a local repository and I would like to view all versions of a file.  I can do this crudely by first finding all the commit ids:

```
% git log FILE | perl -nE '/\Acommit ([0-9a-f]+)\s*\z/ && say $1' log >commits
```

and then getting FILE's text for each id:

```
% for i in `cat commits`; do git show $i:FILE; done
```

That runs one 'git' process for each revision, which is slower than it needs to be.  (Git is fast, but not so fast that I want to fork a subprocess for each revision of the file.  A quick benchmark shows that running a separate 'git show' process for each revision churns through about 50 commits per second, and I have over 5000 commits to this file.)

Luckily 'git show' allows you to view more than one revision at a time, e.g.

```
% git show REV1:FILE REV2:FILE
```

That runs only a single subprocess for all the revisions.  But it concatenates them together with no marker so it would be hard for a program to determine where one ends and the next begins.  Although there is a `--format` option, it doesn't apply to dumping out plain contents and seems to have no effect.

Is there some way I can get all the versions of the file without forking a subprocess for each revision?  I know about Perl's `Git` module but although that has a `cat_blob` method, I so far only have the id of the commits themselves, not an id which would correspond to one file within the commit (if such a thing even exists).

So, there appear to be three alternative ways forward:

- Some option for 'git show' that would let me separate out the different revisions in its output, or write them to separate files, etc.
- Some way to use `Git` or other Perl libraries to directly access the contents of a file in various revisions (without forking a new subprocess for each separate revision)
- Some other tool or library that does what I want more directly or easily.  My end application is to have an enhanced 'blame' tool that shows every line in every version of the file with the revisions where they were introduced and removed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked on the git mailing list, and [`git cat-file --batch`](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/267952) is what you need.  It takes the `REV:FILE` pairs on standard input and outputs the file contents on standard output, in the same order.  Each file is prefixed with a header line giving its length in bytes.